# ¿Filtro de filas en base a ubicación después de un determinado valor en R?

Tags: r, dataframe, filtro

Tengo un archivo en el cual se exportan los resultados de un análisis para una serie de muestras uno debajo del otro. Adicionalmente, solo para algunas de las muestras se exporta información adicional que no es de interés:

```
col1 <- c('RESULTADOS','ID','result','RESULTADOS','ID','result','INFO ADICIONAL','ID','Extra','Extra','RESULTADOS','ID','result')
col2 <- c('','1','f','','2','f','','2','q','w','','3','m')
df1 <- data.frame(col1,col2)
```

El resultado al que quiero llegar es este:

```
ID <- c(1,2,3)
Resultado <- c('f','f','m')
df2 <- data.frame(ID,Resultado)
```

Mi primera duda es si existe alguna forma de indicar en R mediante un bucle o alguna estructura similar que recorra las filas, y a medida que encuentra una celda con “INFO ADICIONAL” elimine esa fila y las 3 posteriores.
Entiendo que podría filter(!col1 %in% c(“INFO ADICIONAL”, Extra, Extra2)), pero en ese caso me queda un ID dando vueltas, que no puedo filtrar de esa manera porque necesito esa información en otras secciones.

Y una vez que se descartaran esas líneas, necesitaría poder indicar que tome el valor de col2 como ID cuando el valor de datos sea ‘ID’, pero no logro llegar a ese resultado aunque me da la impresión de que esa parte no debiera ser muy complicada.

Agradecería mucho cualquier ayuda!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para lograr el primer objetivo primero usamos la función `which` para detectar en el vector `x` las filas donde aparece el texto "INFO ADICIONAL".

Luego con ayuda de un ciclo `for` creamos un vector `filtro` que contenga para cada valor de `x` a los números `c(x, x+1, x+2, x+3)`.

Después a partir de `df1` creamos un `data.frame` auxiliar `aux` donde se eliminen las columnas que posteriormente identificamos en `filtro`.

Ahora filtramos solo las filas  donde `col1`  es `ID` y `result` o lo que seria los mismo eliminar las filas donde `col1` es `RESULTADOS`.

Por ultimo pasamos a formato ancho usando la función `unstack`.

```
x<-which(df1$col1=='INFO ADICIONAL')

filtro<-NULL
for(i in x){
    filtro<-c(filtro,i:(i+3))
}

aux<-df1[-filtro,]

aux<-aux[aux$col1%in%c("ID","result"),]

unstack(aux, form = col2 ~ col1)
```

Enseguida otra forma de llegar al mismo resultado a mi parecer un poco mas sencilla, identificando la columna donde aparece el texto "RESULTADOS" y creando el filtro como las dos filas consecutivas.

```
x<-which(df1$col1=='RESULTADOS')

filtro<-NULL
for(i in x){
    filtro<-c(filtro,(i+1):(i+2))
}

aux<-df1[filtro,]

unstack(aux, form = col2 ~ col1)
```

En ambos casos la salida es

```
> unstack(aux, form = col2 ~ col1)
  ID result
1  1      f
2  2      f
3  3      m
```

Comment: Excelente, gracias! Las funciones which y unstack me van a resultar muy útiles a futuro

Answer (score 1):

Si te animas a usar las herramientas del universo `tidyverse` puedes hacer algo como esto:

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 %>% 
  filter(col1=="ID" | col1=="result") %>% 
  mutate(from=lag(col2))  %>% 
  filter(col1=="result") %>% 
  select(ID=from, result=col2)

  ID result
1  1      f
2  2      f
3  3      m
```

Comentarios:

- con `filter` nos quedamos solo con las filas `ID` y `result`
- buscamos el `ID` para `result` buscando la fila anterior
- Luego filtramos solo las filas `result`